# how to denormalize a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have this data of pokemon and i would like do denormalize this dataframe:

```
#numéro      #nom           #type1          #type2            #poids
1           bulbizard        plante            NaN                 69
2           ivysaur          poison           plante              139
```

To:

```
#numéro              #nom           #type            #poids
1                   bulbizard        plante              69
2                   ivysaur          poison             139
2                   ivysaur          plante              139
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.lreshape` (undocumented):

```
pd.lreshape(df, {'#type': ['#type1', '#type2']})

        #nom  #numéro  #poids   #type
0  bulbizard        1      69  plante
1    ivysaur        2     139  poison
2    ivysaur        2     139  plante
```

---

You can also use `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['#type'], i=['#numéro', ], j='')
   .dropna(subset=['#type'])
   .reset_index(level=0)
   .reset_index(drop=True))

   #numéro       #nom  #poids   #type
0        1  bulbizard      69  plante
1        2    ivysaur     139  poison
2        2    ivysaur     139  plante
```